# rake aborted help

Tags: ruby, rubygems

i don't really know what ruby,gems, or ror is, my objective is make this web application run in my local and after that push it on live. the problem is, when I perform this command
`rake db:migrate`
i am getting an error saying
`rake aborted! Could not find RubyGem rack (~) 1.0.1)`
what should I do ? please help me

Comment: You need to learn what Ruby, Gems and Ruby on Rails are!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's telling you that you need a specific version of the Gem called "rack".  You can install it by doing:

```
gem install rack -v=1.0.1
```

This will only install it to your local gem directory.  If you want to install it globally (which is recommended for production environments), simply do:

```
sudo gem install rack -v=1.0.1
```

This will prompt you for the administrator password as usual.

Comment: now am getting this error sir http://i48.tinypic.com/28l6is1.jpg what should i do next ?

Comment: ok it got fixed by downloading the libmysql.dll file manually and placing it on the "bin" folder of my ruby inside xampp

Answer (score 0):

You need to write this in your command prompt:

```
gem install rack
```